# Jquery datatable sorting not working with Date column

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using Datatable plugin. I want sorting on Date column Descending order but its not working with merender. I want to use `mRender` also to format date. For other column sorting is working perfectly

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wwhy5d2e/

Here is js code:

```
$table = $('#KiList').dataTable({
    bAutoWidth: false,
    aoColumns: [{
        'sWidth': '35%'
    }, {
        'sWidth': '20%',
        "sType": "datetime-us"
    }, {
        'sWidth': '25%',
        "sType": 'string'
    }, {
        'sWidth': '10%',
        "sType": 'string'
    }, {
        'sWidth': '10%',
        "sType": 'string'
    }],
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "aTargets": [1],
        "mRender": function(date, type, full) {
            return moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm a');
        }
    }],
    aaSorting: [[1, 'desc']]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working: [**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wwhy5d2e/3/)

Reference: https://gist.github.com/mark47/10427687

```
$table = $('#KiList').dataTable({
    bAutoWidth: false,
    aoColumns: [{
        'sWidth': '35%'
    }, {
        'sWidth': '20%',
        "type": "datetime-us"//changed
    }, {
        'sWidth': '25%',
        "sType": 'string'
    }, {
        'sWidth': '10%',
        "sType": 'string'
    }, {
        'sWidth': '10%',
        "sType": 'string'
    }],
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "aTargets": [1],
        "mRender": function(date, type, full) {
            return moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm a');
        }
    }],
    aaSorting: [[1, 'desc']]
});
```

Added:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "datetime-us": function ( a ) {
        // If there's no slash, then it's not an actual date, so return zero for sorting
        if(a.indexOf('/') === -1) {
            return '0';
        } else {
                // Set optional items to zero
                var hour = 0,
                    min = 0,
                    ap = 0;
                    // Execute match. Requires month, day, year. Can be mm/dd or m/d. Can be yy or yyyy
                    // Time is optional. am/pm is optional
                    // TODO - remove extra time column from array
                var b = a.match(/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})( (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}))? ?(am|pm|AM|PM|Am|Pm)?/),
                    month = b[1],
                    day = b[2],
                    year = b[3];
                // If time exists then output hours and minutes
                if (b[4] != undefined) {
                    hour = b[5];
                    min = b[6];
                }
                // if using am/pm then change the hour to 24 hour format for sorting
                if (b[7] != undefined) {
                    ap = b[7];
                    if(hour == '12') hour = '0';
                    if(ap == 'pm') hour = parseInt(hour, 10)+12;
                }

                // for 2 digit years, changes to 20__ if less than 70
                if(year.length == 2){
                    if(parseInt(year, 10) < 70) year = '20'+year;
                    else year = '19'+year;
                }
                // Converts single digits
                if(month.length == 1) month = '0'+month;
                if(day.length == 1) day = '0'+day;
                if(hour.length == 1) hour = '0'+hour;
                if(min.length == 1) min = '0'+min;
                var tt = year+month+day+hour+min;

                return tt;
            }
        },
        "datetime-us-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return a - b;
        },
        "datetime-us-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return b - a;
        }
    });
```